# The keyword 'enum' is reserved: symlinked folder, under the src/ directory in create-react-app with typescript, unable to transpile properly

Tags: typescript, enums, create-react-app, symlink

Having an issue with enums when symlinking a common enums and interfaces directory (named common, symlinked within src/ folder). For some reason, importing interfaces from this folder doesn't trigger an error, but importing the enum files does trigger an error!

Things that might help: (1) importing modules from outside the src folder. CRA with typescript only transpiles folders under src/, so I symlinked the folder to be inside src. (2) I can make a copy of those exact enums, declare them in a separate file within src/, run yarn start, and no error is thrown! It must be some odd interaction between the symlinked folder and CRA.

ERROR
[image]

DIRECTORY STRUCTURE
[image]

Notice, using a monorepo with typescript, create-react-app with typescript template for the frontend. Again I can import interfaces from the symlinked common folder with no errors, only when I import the enums do I have a problem.

Here's the code for the ../common/enums/Subject.ts file:

```
enum Subject {
  Biology = 'BIOLOGY',
  Chemistry = 'CHEMISTRY',
  Earth = 'EARTH',
  Energy = 'ENERGY',
  General = 'GENERAL',
  Math = 'MATH',
  Physics = 'PHYSICS',
  Space = 'SPACE'
}

export default Subject;
```

And for good measure (maybe it's my tsconfig.json??) Here's my tsconfig.json for the frontend:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "es6"
    ],
    "target": "es6",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```

I do have a tsconfig.json for the common folder, but not sure that woud be causing the issue. here's the structure of the common folder and tsconfig.json file for it.

[image]

Comment: Did you export the enum? `export enum Subject {`

Comment: Yes - let me update that in the code there (have `export default Subject;` at the bottom of that file)

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? I face the exact same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not :/. I abandoned this solution entirely and just created a private npm package (costs $7 a month though)

Comment: Same issue. Please upvote to get attention.